# Evaluation of double integral – Polar Coordinates?

Tags: integration, analysis, improper-integrals, polar-coordinates

I am trying to calculate the double integral $$\int_0^{\infty}\int_0^{\infty}e^{-2x^2-3y^2}\, dx\, dy$$ If both coefficients of $x^2$ and $y^2$ were equal then we could use polar coordinates.

Can we do that also in this case?

Then we would have $$\int\int e^{-r^2-r^2\cos^2\theta}\, r\, dr\, d\theta$$ But how can we continue from here? Or do we do something else here?

Comment: Just use $e^{-2x^2-3y^2} = e^{-2x^2} e^{-3y^2}$

Comment: Do we not need polar coordinates? @TimurBakiev

Comment: I’m sure we don’t

Comment: Polar coordinates are the well-known trick to calculate the Gaussian integral

Comment: I think he's thinking of using the [Fubini-Tonelli theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem). Alternatively there's likely a way to do it involving some form of elliptical coordinate system but this should be the cleanest/most elegant

Comment: @StephenDonovan yes, very likely

Comment: @MaryStar Do you know the result of $\int_{(0,+\infty)}e^{-\alpha x^2}dx$ ?

Comment: You know I came back to look at this and I realized my comment from before doesn't make a ton of sense, I was thinking of a corollary to Fubini's theorem instead of the actual statement. Oops

Answer (score 2):

$$I=\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty e^{-(2x^2+3y^2)}\,dx\,dy$$
now let $X=\sqrt{2}x\Rightarrow dx=\frac{dX}{\sqrt{2}}$ and $Y=\sqrt{3}y\Rightarrow dy=\frac{dY}{\sqrt{3}}$ so we get:
$$I=\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty e^{-(X^2+Y^2)}\,dX\,dY$$
now use your polar coordinates

Answer (score 1):

If you already know the result from the Gaussian integral, $\int_0^\infty e^{-ax^2} dx = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}$ (for $Re(a) > 0$) then you can simply break up the integral like this:

$$\int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty e^{-2x^2 - 3y^2} dx dy = \int_0^\infty e^{-2x^2} \left[ \int_0^\infty e^{-3y^2} dy \right] dx = \int^{\infty}_0 \sqrt{\frac\pi{3}}e^{-2x^2} dx = \frac\pi{\sqrt{6}}$$

which will match Henry's answer.